# Node Websockets : 1006 Connection dropped by remote peer On Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, websocket

Google Chrome errors out and does not establish websocket connection.

The server logs that established the websocket connection with of the client, and immediately disconnects with the message `1006 Connection dropped by remote peer.`

server code:

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
...
...
}
server.listen(8000);
sessionmgr.sessiongc();
var cons= []
wsServer = new websockserver({
    httpServer: server,
    autoAcceptConnections: false
});
wsServer.on('request', function (req) {
    //console.log(req);
    //accept directly because authenticity of request's origin already established
    var con = req.accept(null, req.origin);
    cons.push(con);
    console.log(cons.length);
    console.log('connection accepted req origin = '+req.origin);
    con.on('message', function(msg) {
        if(msg.type === 'utf8') {
            console.log('Message:='+msg.utf8Data);
            con.sendUTF('Hello'+" "+msg);
        }
        else if(msg.type === 'binary') {
            console.log('Message:='+msg.binary);
            con.sendBytes(msg.binaryData);
        }
    });

    con.on('close',function(reasonCode, description) {
        console.log(con.remoteAddress +'disconnected :: '+reasonCode+" "+description);
    });
});
```

client code:

```
<script>
            window.addEventListener("load",function(evt) {
                var chatbox = document.getElementById("chatbox");
                var send = document.getElementById("send");
                var chathistory = document.getElementById("chathistory");
                var socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.23.128:8000/wp",null);
                socket.addEventListener("open",function(evt) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(evt));
                });
                socket.addEventListener("message",function(evt) {
                    chathistory.innerHTML += evt.data;
                    /*var msgType = jsonMsg['msgType'];
                    switch(msgType) {
                        case 'connectionstatus':
                            updatePlayerConnectionStatus(jsonMsg['payload']);
                            break;
                        case 'chatmsg':
                            updateChat(jsonMsg['payload']);
                            break;
                        case 'scoreupdate':
                            updateScores(jsonMsg['payload']);
                            break;
                    }*/     
                });

                send.addEventListener("click",function(evt) {
                    socket.send(chatbox.value);
                    chatbox.value = "";
                });
            });
        </script>
```

The connection does not drop when I use Firefox. It only drops when I try to connect using Google Chrome.

Error in Chrome Console:

```
 WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.23.128:8000/wp' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received
```

However no error while using Firefox. Any ideas on how to make sure it works on Chrome as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when connecting noVNC client (binary websocket) to netty websocket server. and solved it by setting the subprotocol on server side:

```
public class NoVncProxyServer extends WebSocketServer {

public NoVncProxyServer(int port) {
    super(port);
}

@Override
protected void initialize(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
    pipeline.addLast(
            new HttpServerCodec(),
            new HttpObjectAggregator(65536),
            /*
             Fixed chrome web socket handshake error by setting sub protocols:

             WebSocket connection to 'ws://192.168.8.157:35223/websocket' failed:
                Error during WebSocket handshake:
                Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received

             */
            new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/websocket", "binary"),
            new BinaryFrameHandler()
    );
}

public static final class BinaryFrameHandler extends
        SimpleChannelInboundHandler<BinaryWebSocketFrame> {

    static final ChannelActivityHandler activityHandler = new ChannelActivityHandler();

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        activityHandler.channelActive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        activityHandler.channelInactive(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        activityHandler.exceptionCaught(ctx, cause);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                             BinaryWebSocketFrame msg) throws Exception {
        // Handle binary frame

        String frontAddress = HostPort.getToString((InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress());
        //transfer data to target by router
        VncProxies.transferRouter.transferTo(frontAddress, msg.content().copy());
    }
}

}
```